# How to concatenete multiple files in different locations?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, concatenation

I hava a root-folder tests, which contain many others folders. Each of these folders also contain folder ad images. In each of those folder is a file info.dat.
How I can merge all of files info.dat in to one info.dat?
The structure:

```
tests -> a1 -> b1 -> info.dat
            -> b2 -> info.dat
            -> b3 -> info.dat
            ...
            -> bn -> info.dat
            1.jpg
            ... 
      -> a2 ...
      -> a3 ...
      ...
      -> an ...
```

How concatenate those info.dat into one file?
I'm on Windows 7.

**UPDATE**
Well, I solved it. 
1. In Total Commander do search for mask *.dat
2. Press button "Files on panel"(actually, I dont know how this button called in eanglish version of Total C.)
3. Copy all files into other folder with parameter "automatically rename files"
4. In this folder run cmd : TYPE *.DAT >> OUTPUT.DAT
5. That's all

Answer (score 0):

Launch this in your tests folder:

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (info.dat) do type "%%a" >>"d:\total.txt"
```